# Diagnosing an autorelease error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I've been playing around with core data and started writing some methods to query different date ranges of data. My core data model is very simple (Entity named Smoke with one field - timestamp (of type date).

When I execute my code, the proper count gets returned, but I get an autorelease error - I used NSZombies to track it to the below method:

```
- (NSUInteger)retrieveSmokesForUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit
{
    NSDate *beginDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    [self rangeForUnit:unit containingDate:[NSDate date] startsAt:&beginDate andEndsAt:&endDate];
    NSInteger count = [self numberOfSmokes:beginDate toDate:endDate];

    [beginDate release];
    [endDate release];

    return count;
}
```

So I get the concept - I am releasing the NSDate objects beginDate and endDate too many times - but why does that happen? I thought the rule was when you instantiate with alloc, you use release? I don't release them explicitly anywhere else in the code, so there must be something going on behind the scenes. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Here are the other methods involved, since the issue must be somewhere in these. I assume it has to do with how I'm passing pointers to the dates around?

The initial call, called in the view controller

```
- (IBAction)cigButtonPressed
{
   NSUInteger smokes = [[DataManager sharedDataManager] retrieveSmokesForUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit];

    NSLog(@"Count test = %i", smokes);
}
```

This calles the method posted a the beginning of the question, which in turn calls:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSmokes:(NSDate *)beginDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate {

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Smoke" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    //Create predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(timeStamp >= %@) AND (timeStamp < %@)", beginDate, endDate];

    //Setup request
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSUInteger smokes = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Number of smokes retrieved: %d", smokes);
    [request release];
    return smokes;    
}
```

Thanks!

Edit - left out a related method:

```
- (void)rangeForUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit containingDate:(NSDate *)currentDate startsAt:(NSDate **)startDate andEndsAt:(NSDate **)endDate {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&*startDate interval:0 forDate:currentDate];
    *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:[self offsetComponentOfUnit:unit] toDate:*startDate options:0];
    [calendar release];
}
```

Comment: When I've had an autorelease problem (which produces frustratingly little debug info) I've managed to narrow it down by creating and draining autorelease pools around blocks of code (taking care to retain any values that must persist across the `drain`).  You'll eventually get down to a small area where your pool provokes the problem.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to the [beginDate release] and [endDate release] lines in retrieveSmokesForUnit...if I remove those, it runs fine with no crashes...

Comment: Ah, with the added code the problem is pretty obvious.  You create the (retained) date objects, then overlay them with autoreleased versions in rangeForUnit, then release the autoreleased versions (leaving the original date objects leaking, BTW).

Comment: Isn't the & in `[calendar rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&*startDate` wrong? rangeOfUnit doesn't modify startDate.

Comment: @ott That `&*` ends up being a no-op and could be removed.

Comment: I removed the ampersand, and now I get a warning: "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'NSDate **'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
- (void)rangeForUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit containingDate:(NSDate *)currentDate startsAt:(NSDate **)startDate andEndsAt:(NSDate **)endDate {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&*startDate interval:0 forDate:currentDate];
    *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:[self offsetComponentOfUnit:unit] toDate:*startDate options:0];
    [calendar release];
}
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are output parameters. They are **not** owned by the caller, hence they should **not** be released.

Then, in:

```
- (NSUInteger)retrieveSmokesForUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit
{
    NSDate *beginDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    [self rangeForUnit:unit containingDate:[NSDate date] startsAt:&beginDate andEndsAt:&endDate];
    NSInteger count = [self numberOfSmokes:beginDate toDate:endDate];

    [beginDate release];
    [endDate release];

    return count;
}
```

the following happens:

1. You create a new `NSDate` object via `+alloc`, hence you own it. `beginDate` points to this new object;
2. You create a new `NSDate` object via `+alloc`, hence you own it. `endDate` points to this new object;
3. You send `-rangeUnit:containingDate:startsAt:andEndsAt:`, passing the address of `beginDate` and `endDate` as arguments. Upon return, these two variables point to whatever was placed in them by the method. You do **not** own the corresponding objects (see above), and you’ve leaked the two `NSDate` objects you created in steps 1 and 2.
4. You send `-release` to both `beginDate` and `endDate`. You don’t own them, hence you shouldn’t release them.

In summary:

- You shouldn’t be creating new objects for `beginDate` and `endDate` since they’re being returned by `-rangeUnit…` This causes memory leaks;
- You shouldn’t be releasing `beginDate` and `endDate` because you do not own the objects returned by `-rangeUnit…` This causes overreleases.

The following code should fix your leaks and overreleases:

```
- (NSUInteger)retrieveSmokesForUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit
{
    NSDate *beginDate;
    NSDate *endDate;
    [self rangeForUnit:unit containingDate:[NSDate date] startsAt:&beginDate andEndsAt:&endDate];
    NSInteger count = [self numberOfSmokes:beginDate toDate:endDate];

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your excellent explanation has brought me one step closer to understanding Obj-C memory management. Thank you very much!!